# In SQL or MySQL, can we join a table and a subquery result?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, subquery

Can we join a table with the result of a subquery, such as:

```
select name from gifts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (select giftID from gifts) ...
```

If not, can it be done by some methods, such as creating a temporary table?

P.S. Can a subquery only appear using   IN or NOT IN, or EXISTS or NOT EXISTS?

Comment: what you describe is called an derived table or an inline view and is quite common. I could not live without them!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, sql works on sets; a subquery returns a set as result, so this is possible.

You have to give the subquery a name: `(SELECT * FROM table) AS sub` or `(SELECT * FROM table) sub`. As full query:

```
SELECT name FROM gifts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT giftID FROM gifts) AS sub
    ON ...
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 8):

yes you can use a select as an INNER JOIN you just have to give it an alias:

```
SELECT Name FROM Transactions T
INNER JOIN (SELECT Distinct customerID As CustomerID FROM Customers) A 
ON A.CustomerID = T.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, could be to create a VIEW of the subquery. Then do a JOIN as you would normally would (by referencing the VIEW).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustomerId,
       Name,
       Address
FROM Table1 M
INNER JOIN Table2 C ON M.CustomerId=C.CustomerId
WHERE CustomerId IN
    (SELECT CustomerId
     FROM Table1 M
     INNER JOIN Table2 ON M.CustomeID=C.CustomerId)
ORDER BY CustomerId,
         Name,
         Address
```